# Distinct Append in Select

Tags: jquery

> How will i distinct the value of select when i append. see the sample output below

[image]

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#example2").on('click',"tr#paymentedit", "click", function(data){


        var valuetoedit = new Option(($(this).find('td:eq(2)').html()), "value");
    valuetoedit.selected=true;
    $("#paymenttypeedit").append(valuetoedit);      
        });
    });
```

Comment: Why are you allowing users to enter free form payment types at all?

Comment: its a edit payment once i click the tr it will copy the value and change it freely

Answer (score 0):

Test each option to see if one exists that has a value that compares similarly and perhaps replace the value entered with the existing one (or visa versa)

You probably want to avoid using the text/label of an option as the value.  if you don't decide to do that there's no point to setting all the values to "value"  (Use `valuetoedit = new Option(($(this).find('td:eq(2)').html()));` instead)

```js
function foo() {
 var valuetoedit = $('#foo').val();
 var uniq = true;
 var options = $("#paymenttypeedit option");
 for(var i=0; uniq && i < options.length; i++) {
     if (valuetoedit.toUpperCase() === options[i].text.toUpperCase()) {
         uniq = false;
         valuetoedit = this.text; // use the existing value
     }
 }
 if (uniq) {
     $("#paymenttypeedit").append(new Option(valuetoedit, null, false, true));
 }
}

function init() {
 $('#but').on('click', foo);
}

$(document).ready(init);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="paymenttypeedit"></select>
<input id="foo" type="text">
<button id="but">&nbsp;</button>
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
$("#example2").one('click',"tr#paymentedit", "click", function(data){
 
var uniq = true;
var options = $("#paymenttypeedit option");
for(var i=0; uniq && i < options.length; i++) {
    if (valuetoedit.toUpperCase() === options[i].value.toUpperCase()) {
        uniq = false;
        valuetoedit = this.value; // use the existing value
    }
}
if (uniq) {
var valuetoedit = new Option(($(this).find('td:eq(2)').html()), "value");
valuetoedit.selected=true;
$("#paymenttypeedit").append(valuetoedit);  
}
 
 

    });
});

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see you were setting all the `value` properties to "value".  I'm modified the code to use `text` instead

Comment: valuetoedit = new Option(($(this).find('td:eq(2)').html()));
var uniq = true;
var options = $("#paymenttypeedit option");
for(var i=0; uniq && i < options.length; i++) {
    if (valuetoedit.toUpperCase() === options[i].text.toUpperCase()) {
        uniq = false;
        valuetoedit = this.text; // use the existing value
    }
}
if (uniq) {
     var valuetoedit = new Option(($(this).find('td:eq(2)').html()), "value");
valuetoedit.selected=true;
$("#paymenttypeedit").append(valuetoedit);
}

Comment: Not sure what you're doing.  I've done a snippet that works

Comment: im clicking in TR and getting the value of td

Comment: @ShermaineChaingan I have no idea what that means.  You didn't put any HTML in your question and only a tiny piece of JS, so it's really hard to know what exactly you're doing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123194/discussion-between-shermaine-chaingan-and-tibrogargan).